# PHP - create a non-interactive copy of a web page, perhaps PDF?

Tags: php, html, pdf

What I have is a search form that submits to the same page and it fetches the results using an AJAX request.

This uses the POST method and I am trying to figure out a way to try and do something along the lines of having a button to open this page in a new window to preserve the search parameters and results and to allow it to be bookmarkable somehow but I can't really think how to do this.

The other main reason for doing this is because the search results contain links to if a user clicks one and then clicks back all the form parameters are lost, I have worked around this by having the links open in a new window.

Any help, advice and opinions would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you use $_GET to submit the search parameters then the results will be inherently bookmarkable (provided the same parameters always return the same results).  This is why there are two methods for submitting parameters over HTTP. While it's not set in stone that you use $_GET to retrieve data and $_POST to change it, it's generally considered good practice if you do.

Comment: I changed everything from POST to GET but the url is not populated with the parameters, I'm guessing this is because the form is processed using AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a GET method instead of POST, then the user will get to an URL with its form parameters in it.

It won't have to be ajax anymore

Comment: Thanks, but I want my form to stay the away it is, just trying to allow bookmarking somehow.

Do you think it's possible to create a new page that uses the GET method that users can bookmark?